# How to set Windows application ToolstripMenuItems Text Foreground Color Change When Hover Mouse in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

Windows application ToolstripMenuItems Text Foreground Color Change When Hover Mouse in C#

[image: My ToolStripMenuItems .Click Here to Show]

Answer (score 0):

Use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave event as follows:

```
   private void helpToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        helpToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }

   private void helpToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        helpToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

Comment: I mean It Will Change Foreground For Menu Head Not SubMenu Items. Ex In Above Image Menu Head Foreground Change like **Master**,**Purchase** `private void purchaseToolStripMenuItem_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            purchaseToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void purchaseToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            purchaseToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }`

Comment: In the design view go to the sub-menu item and right click properties. In the properties window click the lightning bolt for a list of events, then double click the event you want to access. Then add your code to this event handler.

Comment: Each menu item has a unique name property, in your code you are reffering to the purchaseToolStripMenuItem Your Main and sub center tab will have a different name property. Have also found that using the MouseEnter event works a little better.

Comment: I think the problem is not changing the background color but the default highlighting...Try this. Add the following code:

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            menuStrip1.Renderer = new NewColourRenderer();
        }

Comment: private class NewColourRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
        {public NewColourRenderer()
                : base(new MyColours()) { }
            private class MyColours : ProfessionalColorTable
            {public override Color MenuItemSelected
                {get { return Color.Cyan; }
                }
                public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientBegin
                {get { return Color.DarkCyan; }
                }
                public override Color MenuItemSelectedGradientEnd
                {get { return Color.Cyan; } }
            } }

Comment: Your answer has an edit link.  Use it for your code updates.

Comment: Not working All the above comments are change only background not in foreground. Only i want Change Foreground color.@Darren

Comment: What is the name property of the menu item you want to change?

Comment: menu property Name is **masterToolStripMenuItem**,**purchaseToolStripMenuItem**,**reportsToolStripMenuItem** etc..these are the property Name of menu. I want to change foreground color of text in the menu items to **White color**  like **Member and Shares Entry**,**Place and caste Entry** text etc.. when i am Mouse Hover menu items. And then mouse leave Again Back to **Black color** @Darren

Comment: I will stick with the first answer but use MouseEnter instead of Mouse_Hover:
private void masterToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            helloToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }

        private void masterToolStripMenuItem_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            helloToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
Do this for each menu item...